# Angular Material - Right Sidebar Bugs, left not, but same code?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I build my first app with the material framework: http://thommessen.upperyard.de/ When you switch the website to mobile view, and open the RIGHT Sidebar, then you will see that he bugs in the height of the site... the left sidebar dont bug, but its exactly the same code, i kust change the id to right and the class to right. can anyone tell me how this can be?

Here the code:

```
<div ui-view="header">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button">
                <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="images/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('right')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button">
                <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="images/icons/student.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
</div>

<div layout="row" flex>

    <div ui-view="sidebar-left">
        <md-sidenav layout="column"
                    class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2"
                    md-component-id="left"
                    md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
            asdsd
        </md-sidenav>
    </div>

    <div layout="column" flex id="content">
        <md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding">

            <div ui-view="container"></div>

        </md-content>
    </div>

    <div ui-view="sidebar-right">
        <md-sidenav layout="column"
                    class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-z2"
                    md-component-id="right"
                    md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
            asdsd
        </md-sidenav>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can't Reproduce, is it on a mobile device or anytime you shrink the page? Is it browser or os specific?

Comment: Just shrink the websites width and height. then you will see. i use Chrome in a Windows PC. But i got the same problem on Chrome on my Android.

Comment: Works fine on Firefox on Ubuntu, but it messes up on android chrome and windows Firefox as well..

Comment: Here i add a Video that everyone can see the Problem: https://youtu.be/IO5H_3OLWaM The same bug are inside of the Original Demos on the Angular Material Website. So i think alot of people must have this bug. Thats why i am wondering, why no one talk about it.